Astro build freezes after upgrading to v5
I am unable to build my Astro project after upgrading to v5 even though it still runs in dev mode. I use the following command to build the Astro app with Bun:
bunx --bun astro build

and now the build process just gets stuck / frozen on "generating static paths" or something like that. Here is the detailed build output
12:02:10 [ERROR] [vite] x Build failed in 115ms
  astro:telemetry {
  astro:telemetry   context: {
  astro:telemetry     isGit: true,
  astro:telemetry     anonymousProjectId: '657e19201d0e4059df927caaa3fd3f18ee825419873b449ab5841b443e86185c',
  astro:telemetry     packageManager: 'bun',
  astro:telemetry     packageManagerVersion: '1.1.31',
  astro:telemetry     anonymousId: '3a964cc96ef7c8eb9d161d0c704a8dd13118fc7d203353267ccf443ffaf4483a',
  astro:telemetry     anonymousSessionId: 'd494aaa902cd91dff47c2e268373e1d62fbb4f8ca96959728d970094ac02f705'
  astro:telemetry   },
  astro:telemetry   meta: {
  astro:telemetry     nodeVersion: '22.6.0',
  astro:telemetry     viteVersion: '6.0.5',
  astro:telemetry     astroVersion: '5.1.1',
  astro:telemetry     systemPlatform: 'darwin',
  astro:telemetry     systemRelease: '24.0.0',
  astro:telemetry     systemArchitecture: 'arm64',
  astro:telemetry     cpuCount: 10,
  astro:telemetry     cpuModel: 'Apple M1 Max',
  astro:telemetry     cpuSpeed: 2400,
  astro:telemetry     memoryInMb: 65536,
  astro:telemetry     isDocker: false,
  astro:telemetry     isTTY: true,
  astro:telemetry     isWSL: false,
  astro:telemetry     isCI: false,
  astro:telemetry     ciName: null
  astro:telemetry   }
  astro:telemetry } +448ms
  astro:telemetry [
  astro:telemetry   {
  astro:telemetry     "eventName": "ASTRO_CLI_ERROR",
  astro:telemetry     "payload": {
  astro:telemetry       "name": "Error",
  astro:telemetry       "plugin": "commonjs--resolver",
  astro:telemetry       "cliCommand": "build",
  astro:telemetry       "isFatal": true
  astro:telemetry     }
  astro:telemetry   }
  astro:telemetry ] +0ms
[commonjs--resolver] The service was stopped
file: /Users/asleepace/dev/asleepace.com/node_modules/astro/dist/assets/services/service.js
  Stack trace:
    at <anonymous> (/Users/asleepace/dev/asleepace.com/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:737:42)
    at afterClose (/Users/asleepace/dev/asleepace.com/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:613:25)
    at endReadableNT (node:stream:2392:27)


There are quite a few breaking changes in Astro v5 and I would recommend starting a new project and comparing what's changed, also make sure you are able to build the project in development mode, then if you are still having issues use the following commands to track down the root cause
Upgrade Bun
This was the command that eventually fixed everything for me, the automated build process had done most of the work, but somethings I guess were not updated.
bun upgrade

Check for issues
Use this command to track down issues which could be causing the build to fail.
bunx --bun astro check

Debug build
This command provides very detailed build information about the build process and helped me track down the problem (old common-js module resolution)
DEBUG=astro:*,vite:* bunx --bun astro build --verbose

